# Fast way to convert PDF to image

Tags: android

what is the fastest way to convert PDF to Image? I have tried couple of ways but they are very slow. I do not need high resolution but time is very important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the view as Image.
`MyView.buildDrawingCache();`

Then
`Bitmap bmp = myView.getDrawingCache();`

- Edit :

`<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/myview">`

Then in ur activity
`MyLayout.setEnableDrawingCach(true);` then build the drawing and get it as an image like above.

Comment: What do you mean by view? any example ? which library should I use?

Comment: You are wrapping the pdf in what layout?? You can save that layout view by using what i typed above. First enable it using setEnableDrawingCache(true) before u build that layout view cache.

Comment: It works well, Thanks. but the correct function is `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Im using phone to answer the question. So its hard a bit to write the answer with correct spelling. Glad it helped you.

Comment: is there anyway to get another page of pdf without loading the image in the view?

Comment: can you elaborate  more ?

Comment: I need convert all pdf pages to separate images. the above code only will give me the current page which is loaded. how to convert all pages without loading to the view?

Comment: can you show some code and how you displaying the pdf?